# invoke cmd.exe using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cmd

Is there a way to Invoke cmd.exe using client side javascript? Until now i have been using WCF service to run remote processes and execute cmd.exe too. but I need a more reliable way as I don't want to host the WCF services on different systems.

Any sample code will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that.
Ever​​​​​​.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any plugin and big client side relaxing of security settings ?

Of course you can't. Even IE doesn't let you breach user security so easily.

Comment: Ah, I remember when you could make an ActiveX control and delete the Windows folder without asking for permissions... Those were the days!

Comment: And the head of IT department was ensuring nobody could use Netscape because anything not MS was insecure... But now IE is more serious, we can't do this anymore.